# Wordpress стили не подключаются в тег head

Tags: css, wordpress, head

Я новичок вордпресс, недавно столкнулся с неприятным багом. Мне нужно, что бы показ странички был ограничен до полной загрузки 3 стилей (я пометил их в коде комментами со знаками "!"), иначе перед показом сайта на 100-500 милисекунд выскакивает некрасивая версия сайта без стилей (Показано ниже на скрине). Стандартные хуки наподобие wp_head не работают и все равно подключают стили уже после тега head. Вот мой functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head', 'chesmo_styles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chesmo_scripts');
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'chesmo_setup');
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'true_load_theme_textdomain');
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

function chesmo_setup()
{
    load_theme_textdomain('chesmo');
    add_theme_support('menus');
}
function chesmo_scripts () {
    wp_register_script( 'fancybox-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox-js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_jquery_ui', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aos', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/aos.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick_slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_sliders', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/sliders.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'common_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('newscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('contacts_window', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/contacts.js');
}
function chesmo_styles() {
    wp_register_style('header-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header.css');
    wp_register_style('index-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/index.css');
    wp_register_style('bulma-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bulma.min.css');
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    wp_enqueue_style('header-css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bulma-css');
    wp_enqueue_style('index-css');
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    wp_enqueue_style('common-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/common.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('animate-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/aos.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('slick-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slick.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('footer-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/footer.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('fonts-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fancybox-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css' );
    if(is_page_template('tpl_promotions.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('non-main-header-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/non-main-header.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('promotions-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/promotions.css' );
    }
    if(is_page_template('tpl_service.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('service-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/service.css' );
    }
    if(is_page_template('tpl_all_services.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('non-main-header-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/non-main-header.css' );
    }
    if(is_page_template('tpl_calculator.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('non-main-header-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/non-main-header.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('calculator-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/calculator.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'calculator_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/calculator.js');
    }
    if(is_page_template('tpl_contacts.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('non-main-header-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/non-main-header.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('contacts-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/contacts.css' );
    }
    if(is_page_template('tpl_equipment.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('non-main-header-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/non-main-header.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('equipment-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/equipment.css' );
    }
    if(is_page_template('tpl_about.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('about-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/about.css' );
    }
}

function true_load_theme_textdomain(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'chesmo', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}

function chesmo_the_breadcrumb(){
    global $post;
    if(!is_home()){
        if (pll_current_language() == "ru")
            echo '<span><a href="'.site_url().'"><span>Главная</span></a></span>';
        else if (pll_current_language() == "uk")
            echo '<span><a href="'.site_url().'"><span>Головна</span></a></span>';

        if(is_single()){ // posts
            the_category(', ');
            echo " <li> / </li> ";
            echo '<li>';
            the_title();
            echo '</li>';
        }
        elseif (is_page()) { // pages
            if ($post->post_parent ) {
                $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
                $breadcrumbs = array();
                while ($parent_id) {
                    $page = get_post($parent_id);
                    $breadcrumbs[] = '<span><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '"><span>' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</span></a></span>';
                    $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
                }
                $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
                foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb;
            }
            echo '<span>'; echo the_title(); echo '</span>';
        }
        elseif (is_category()) { // category
            global $wp_query;
            $obj_cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
            $current_cat = $obj_cat->term_id;
            $current_cat = get_category($current_cat);
            $parent_cat = get_category($current_cat->parent);
            if ($current_cat->parent != 0)
                echo(get_category_parents($parent_cat, TRUE, ' <li> / </li> '));
            single_cat_title();
        }
        elseif (is_search()) { // search pages
            echo 'Search results "' . get_search_query() . '"';
        }
        elseif (is_tag()) { // tags
            echo single_tag_title('', false);
        }
        elseif (is_day()) { // archive (days)
            echo '<span><a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a></span>';
            echo '<span><a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a></span>';
            echo get_the_time('d');
        }
        elseif (is_month()) { // archive (months)
            echo '<span><a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a></span>';
            echo get_the_time('F');
        }
        elseif (is_year()) { // archive (years)
            echo get_the_time('Y');
        }
        elseif (is_author()) { // authors
            global $author;
            $userdata = get_userdata($author);
            echo '<span>Posted ' . $userdata->display_name . '</span>';
        } elseif (is_404()) { // if page not found
            echo '<span>Error 404</span>';
        }

        if (get_query_var('paged')) // number of page
            echo ' (' . get_query_var('paged').'- page)';

    } else { // home
        $pageNum=(get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        if($pageNum>1)
        {
            if (pll_current_language() == "ru")
                echo '<span><a href="' . site_url() . '"><span>Главная</span></a></span> ' . $pageNum . '- page';
            else if (pll_current_language() == "uk")
                echo '<span><a href="' . site_url() . '"><span>Головна</span></a></span> ' . $pageNum . '- page';

        }
        else
        {
            if (pll_current_language() == "ru")
                echo '<span>Главная</span>';
            else if (pll_current_language() == "uk")
                echo '<span>Головна</span>';

        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите на прелоадеры, чтобы не показывать недозагруженный сайт.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

Используйте правильный хук для постановки стилей в очередь - `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Обычно функции `wp_enqueue_script()` и `wp_enqueue_style()` используют внутри одной функции, в вашем случае - `chesmo_scripts()`.

**Объяснение**

Надо понимать, что функции `wp_enqueue_script()` и `wp_enqueue_style()` не делают ничего, лишь ставят скрипты в очередь (заносят их в массив в ядре). Вывод стилей и скриптов производится на хуке `wp_print_scripts`, который срабатывает после `wp_enqueue_scripts`, но ДО `wp_head`. Поэтому ваши скрипты в хедер уже не попадают, остаются в очереди (массиве) и выводятся ядром уже в футере. Вот почему вы видите некоторое время сайт без нужных вам стилей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, уже разобрался

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.